# How to unbind a binding from JGoodies-Binding (2.9.0)

Tags: java, swing, jgoodies

I have the rare use case, where the swing-view lives longer than the related presentation-model: The swing-view lives as long as the application lives, the presentation-model is replaced each time a new "run" is started in the application.

The presentation-model is a groovy bean:

```
@Bindable
static class MyPresentationModel{
   String myText = 'default-text'
}
```

The swing-view is a JTextField, bound using a JGoodies BeanAdapter:

```
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField()
MyPresentationModel pm = new MyPresentationModel()
BeanAdapter<MyPresentationModel> beanAdapter = new BeanAdapter<MyPresentationModel>(pm, true)
Bindings.bind(myTextField , beanAdapter.getValueModel('myText'))
```

How can I **unbind** the presentation model from the JTextField afterwards?

The only thing in that direction I found in the JGoodies-Binding API is

```
beanAdapter.setBean(null)
```

But this doesn't - of course - remove the JGoodies-PropertyChangeListener and the JGoodies-DocumentListener from the JTextField. Is there a a nice way to remove those? Or do I have hack it down myself?

Answer (score 0):

The only way as far as i know is to call

```
Bindings.bind(myTextField , beanAdapter.getValueModel('myText'))
```

the above statement everytime with a new bean adapter from a new PresentationModel.

You cannot unbind a binding, you will have to refresh the binding with a new PresentationModel

Comment: Assuming you've got a BeanAdapter, I've had limited success using `beanAdapter.release()` to cause the `BeanAdapter` instance to drop all `PropertyChangeListeners` that are registered with bean adapter. But like I said, success was limited, and it depends greatly on how your beans, bean adapters, and ui components are wired together.